# Network Disabled in Windows wsl 2 having ubuntu 20.04

Tags: windows-subsystem-for-linux

I installed WSL2 in Windows with Ubuntu 20.04 distro, When I tried updating and upgrading it showed network was in Unreachable. Though my internet connection is all good. I checked the network details with "***sudo lshw -C network***", I found the following details:

```
 sudo lshw -C network
  *-network:0 DISABLED
       description: Ethernet interface
       physical id: 1
       logical name: bond0
       serial: 0a:f8:9c:51:91:fe
       capabilities: ethernet physical
sangramz@sangramzSYS:~$
  *-network:1 DISABLED
       description: Ethernet interface
       physical id: 2
       logical name: dummy0
       serial: 56:b8:ff:c1:d2:a9
       capabilities: ethernet physical
       configuration: broadcast=yes driver=dummy driverversion=5.10.102.1-microsoft-standard-W
  *-network:2
       description: Ethernet interface
       physical id: 3
       logical name: eth0
       serial: 00:15:5d:85:70:43
       size: 10Gbit/s
       capabilities: ethernet physical
       configuration: autonegotiation=off broadcast=yes driver=hv_netvsc driverversion=5.10.102.1-microsoft-standard-W duplex=full firmware=N/A ip=172.28.61.160 link=yes multicast=yes speed=10Gbit/s
```

I can see I'm not able to do anything like updating or upgrading or installing new packages. Errors while doing Sudo apt Update and Python Pip installs:

[image: Screenshot]